# Serial Commands - NEC Projector

Tags: c#, com, serial-port

I'm working on a C# application that writes serial commands to an NEC projector. I can send the commands fine using `RealTerm` using the "Send Numbers" function but cannot seem to get it to work through my app.

The format of the commands are

**`POWER ON   -                     02H 00H 00H 00H 00H 02H`**

**`POWER OFF  -                     02H 01H 00H 00H 00H 03H`**

I've tried sending using `WriteLine(command)` - as a string as well as converting it to a byte array with the following code:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(string StringToConvert)
{
    char[] CharArray = StringToConvert.ToCharArray();
    byte[] ByteArray = new byte[CharArray.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < CharArray.Length; i++)
    {
        ByteArray[i] = Convert.ToByte(CharArray[i]);
    }

    return ByteArray;
}
```

Nothing seems to work, what shall I be sending down the port from my C# end? Hopefully someone can help soon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very little point in trying to convert these commands from a string.  They are not  strings.  So just write them in your code in their native format:

```
private byte[] powerOnCmd  = new byte[] { 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02 };
private byte[] powerOffCmd = new byte[] { 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03 };
```

Now it is simple:

```
private void sendCommand(byte[] cmd) {
   serialPort1.Write(cmd, 0, cmd.Length);
}
private void PowerOn() {
   sendCommand(powerOnCmd);
}
```

Comment: I was going to do it this way but the client wanted to send a number of different commands remotely using a web interface. I've sorted it now anyway basically doing what you've suggested here only I made a little script to parse the string and converted them to their native format :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Write method, it takes a string as argument :

[SerialPort.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2sxhat8.aspx)

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't seem to work again for some reason :/ I'll try it again and make sure I'm doing it right! :P Thanks